# Including a static library in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a directory structure

trunk

--lib--libParser.a

--objs

--src

--Makefile

I have the following makefile

```
CRYPTOLIB_TARGET = cryptolib.a 

LOCALLIBS = ./objs
LOCALLIBS_IMAGE = ./cryptolib.a
CC = gcc
AR = ar
DEBUG_FLAGS = 
LDEFSECOM_LOG_VERSION = -DSECOM_LOG_VERSION
CMPL_TIME_MACROS = -DENBL_DEBUG_PRINTF $(LDEFSECOM_LOG_VERSION)
ALLWARN = 
ALL_INCS = -I./src/INCLUDE
LIBS = -lrt -laio -lrt -lpthread -lm -lpq -ldl

LINK = $(CC) $(DEBUG_FLAGS) $(CMPL_TIME_MACROS) $(ALLWARN) $(ALL_INCS) $(LIBS) -c

default = CRYPTOLIB_TARGET

CRYPTOLIB_OBJ =             \
$(LOCALLIBS)/AES_crypt.o    \
$(LOCALLIBS)/bigdigits.o    \
$(LOCALLIBS)/DataEncryption.o   \
$(LOCALLIBS)/SiaEncryption.o

$(CRYPTOLIB_TARGET): $(CRYPTOLIB_OBJ)
$(AR) r $(CRYPTOLIB_TARGET) $(CRYPTOLIB_OBJ)

$(LOCALLIBS)/AES_crypt.o : \
src/AES_crypt.c
mkdir -p ./objs
$(LINK) src/AES_crypt.c -o $(LOCALLIBS)/AES_crypt.o

$(LOCALLIBS)/bigdigits.o : \
src/bigdigits.c
$(LINK) src/bigdigits.c -o $(LOCALLIBS)/bigdigits.o

$(LOCALLIBS)/DataEncryption.o : \
src/DataEncryption.c
$(LINK) src/DataEncryption.c -o $(LOCALLIBS)/DataEncryption.o

$(LOCALLIBS)/SiaEncryption.o : \
src/SiaEncryption.c
$(LINK) src/SiaEncryption.c -o $(LOCALLIBS)/SiaEncryption.o

clean:
rm -rf objs
rm -rf cryptolib.a
```

I want to include the libParser.a in the output library which I am creating but I am not sure how to do that. Can you please give me the pointers to so that I can include the library(libParser.a) and create cryptolib.a as a final output library.

Comment: Do you want a rule that can build `libParser.a`, or will you just assume that it exists? And do you know how to build `cryptolib.a` the way you want on the command line?

Comment: I will assume that it exits so I dont want to build it. Yes i am able to build cryptolib.a but i want to link libParser.a with cryptolib. I have put a new line here LIBS = -l./lib/libParser.a -lrt -laio -lrt -lpthread -lm -lpq -ldl, I was able to link the library after putting this line. Can you suggest if there are some other ways for the same?

Answer (score 1):

from [gcc online docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html):

> *-llibrary*
>
> *-l library*
>
> ...(text removed)...
>
> Normally the files found this way are library files—archive files
>   whose members are object files. The linker handles an archive file by
>   scanning through it for members which define symbols that have so far
>   been referenced but not defined. But if the file that is found is an
>   ordinary object file, it is linked in the usual fashion. The only
>   difference between using an -l option and specifying a file name is
>   that -l surrounds library with ‘lib’ and ‘.a’ and searches several
>   directories.

So... you could specify the library include folder:

```
-L./lib
```

and put the libParser.a in the list of libraries (subracting 'lib' and '.a'):

```
-lParser -lrt -laio ...
```